fetch vault info error: 111115X9BNuV9BeVkKmcU1WzeKpMyRbpMrbiabeots using Raydium AMM `getPoolInfoFromRpc` method
I am getting the following error trying to fetch details about a Raydium AMM pool using the getPoolInfoFromRpc method
1 | var Im=Object.create;var eo=Object.defineProperty,Bm=Object.defineProperties,xm=Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor,Sm=Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors,Km=Object.getOwnPropertyNames,tr=Object.getOwnPropertySymbols,Cm=Object.getPrototypeOf,Ms=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,Hu=Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable;var ju=(i,e,t)=>e in i?eo(i,e,{enumerable:!0,configurable:!0,writable:!0,value:t}):i[e]=t,O=(i,e)=>{for(var t in e||(e={}))Ms.call(e,t)&&ju(i,t,e[t]);if(tr)for(var t of tr(e))Hu.call(e,t)&&ju(i,t,e[t]);return i},q=(i,e)=>Bm(i,Sm(e));var Qe=(i,e)=>{var t={};for(var n in i)Ms.call(i,n)&&e.indexOf(n)<0&&(t[n]=i[n]);if(i!=null&&tr)for(var n of tr(i))e.indexOf(n)<0&&Hu.call(i,n)&&(t[n]=i[n]);return t};var Rm=(i,e)=>{for(var t in e)eo(i,t,{get:e[t],enumerable:!0})},Zu=(i,e,t,n)=>{if(e&&typeof e=="object"||typeof e=="function")for(let o of Km(e))!Ms.call(i,o)&&o!==t&&eo(i,o,{get:()=>e[o],enumerable:!(n=xm(e,o))||n.enumerable});return i};var fe=(i,e,t)=>(t=i!=null?Im(Cm(i)):{},Zu(e||!i||!i.__esModule?eo(t,"defau | ... truncated

error: fetch vault info error: 111115X9BNuV9BeVkKmcU1WzeKpMyRbpMrbiabeots
      at /home/jimii/Documents/webcode/test-raydium/node_modules/@raydium-io/raydium-sdk-v2/lib/index.js:1:293377

My code
export async function fetchAMMPoolDetailsUsingRPC(poolId: string) {
    const { poolInfo, poolKeys, poolRpcData } =
        await raydium.liquidity.getPoolInfoFromRpc({
            poolId: poolId,
        });

    return { poolInfo, poolKeys, rpcData: poolRpcData };
}

const poolId = "2AJ4mHj3BuWEGbHq7nYDXxzdiLYSgXMH7sZrsc9JjP8U"; // sol - dream
const resp = await fetchAMMPoolDetailsUsingRPC(poolId);
console.log(resp);

